# Transfer data from input to another input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some inputs. "input and select" data in the id value of "customer-1", I want to match and transfer with "class" value if click add button. 
For example, id="customer-1" "input and select" data in, I want it imported into class="customer-1".

```js
$('.customer-add').click(function(){
 var customer_id = $('.customer-add').closest('.customer-bar').find("input").attr("id");

    $("." + customer_id).val($("#" + customer_id).val());
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="customer-bar">
     <div id="customer-1">
      <input type="text" id="customer-name" value="john" disabled />
      <input type="text" id="customer-surnamename" value="doe" disabled />
      <select name="" id="customer-day" disabled>
       <option value="">14</option>
      </select>
      <select name="" id="customer-month" disabled>
       <option value="">02</option>
      </select>
      <select name="" id="customer-year" disabled>
       <option value="">1995</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    <br />
     <div class="customer-add" style="cursor:pointer;background:red;color:white;display:inline-block;">Click to add customer details</div>
    <br /><br />
     <div class="customer-1">
      <input type="text" class="customer-name" value="" />
      <input type="text" class="customer-surnamename" value="" />
      <select name="" class="customer-day">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="">2</option>
       <option value="">3</option>
       <option value="">4</option>
      </select>
      <select name="" class="customer-month">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="">2</option>
       <option value="">3</option>
       <option value="">4</option>
      </select>
      <select name="" class="customer-year">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="">2012</option>
       <option value="">2015</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <br><br><br>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="customer-bar">
     <div id="customer-2">
      <input type="text" id="customer-name" value="john" disabled />
      <input type="text" id="customer-surnamename" value="doe" disabled />
      <select name="" id="customer-day" disabled>
       <option value="">14</option>
      </select>
      <select name="" id="customer-month" disabled>
       <option value="">02</option>
      </select>
      <select name="" id="customer-year" disabled>
       <option value="">1995</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    <br />
     <div class="customer-add" style="cursor:pointer;background:red;color:white;display:inline-block;">Click to add customer details</div>
    <br /><br />
     <div class="customer-2">
      <input type="text" class="customer-name" value="" />
      <input type="text" class="customer-surnamename" value="" />
      <select name="" class="customer-day">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="">2</option>
       <option value="">3</option>
       <option value="">4</option>
      </select>
      <select name="" class="customer-month">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="">2</option>
       <option value="">3</option>
       <option value="">4</option>
      </select>
      <select name="" class="customer-year">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="">2012</option>
       <option value="">2015</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
```

I updated my code. I was able to transfer a single input, but I have to transfer them all

Comment: What did you try? You for sure first need to change all the duplicate IDs to class

Comment: I think you might need to explain a little more. I struggle to understand the exact issue.

Comment: When I click ".customer-1-add", I want to place the above data in the inputs below. I'm trying something right now

Comment: i updated my first post

Answer (score 0):

1. Change id to class
2. use closest and next

I assume you meant copy from customer1 to customer2

I cannot make a working snippet because you have the same IDs and no names, but the code will look this this

```
$(function() {
  $(".customer-add").on("click",function() {
    const $container = $(this).closest(".customer-bar")
    const $nextContainer = $container.next(".customer-bar")
    const $currentElements = $(":input",$container);
    const $nextElements = $(":input",$nextContainer);
    $currentElements.each(function(i) {
      console.log(i,$(this).attr("class"))
      $nextElements.eq(i).val($(this).val())
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated my code. I was able to transfer a single input, but I have to transfer them all